# Universal image loader on Android Studio

Tags: android

I tried to run it on eclip and it works but on android studio, it fails. I can not find a solution to this problem. I want to load a photo from openFirst(), Error openFirst()

```
public class MidFragment extends Fragment {
//    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private View mView;
    private DisplayImageOptions mOptions;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private Context mContext;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
    private ArrayList<ParseObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mid_fragment, container, false);
        initComponent();
        mContext = container.getContext();
        return mView;

    }

    private void initComponent() {
        mImageView = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        mVideoView = (VideoView)mView.findViewById(R.id.video);
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        mVideoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
//        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
//        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait a moment...");
//        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    }

    public void reloadData(int index){
//        mProgressDialog.show();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Data");
        query.whereEqualTo("school",(Number)index);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                objectList = (ArrayList<ParseObject>) list;
//                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if (!list.isEmpty())
                    openFirst();
            }
        });
    }
    private void openFirst(){

        mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        mImageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
        mOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();
            ParseObject parseObject = objectList.get(0);
            ParseFile parseFile = parseObject.getParseFile("file");
            Log.e("****************************",""+parseFile.getUrl());
        if (parseObject.getNumber("type") == (Number)1){
//            mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//            mVideoView.setVideoURI();
        }else{
            mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(parseFile.getUrl(), mImageView, mOptions, animateFirstListener);

        }
    }

    private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
05-18 23:23:02.258  10496-10496/animuco.com.ckemi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: animuco.com.ckemi, PID: 10496
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder.<init>(ImageLoaderConfiguration.java:196)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ImageLoaderConfiguration.java:127)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.MidFragment.openFirst(MidFragment.java:99)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.MidFragment.access$200(MidFragment.java:42)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.MidFragment$3.done(MidFragment.java:92)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.MidFragment$3.done(MidFragment.java:86)
            at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:944)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly `mContext` is null. Since this is fragment just remove mContext and use getActivity() instead.

Comment: There is no line in your code that calls reloadData and openFirst. You might call these methods before the fragment is created. That's why getActivity returns null.